# Cylindrical pressure vessel

Tags: projectile, aerodynamics

For a cylindrical pressure vessel that is placed horizontally on the ground. One end has a plug that comes off when the pressure increases ( it is the failure mode) . If the pressure inside is 300 Psi. Once it exceeds 300 Psi the plug will come off. If so. how far would the plug fly off. The pressure acting on the plug is 300 psi. But I do not know the initial velocity right before it flies out. How do I determine the distance travelled ?

Comment: Hi, please don't repost the same question. Instead, [improve your existing question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653744)

Comment: James. What is the surface area of the plug and what is its mass?

Comment: My previous question was closed that’s why I had to repost.

Comment: Hi Joseph. Mass is 15 kg and surface area is 0.8m2. Thank you.

Comment: If your question was closed, you have to edit it to be eligible to be reopened. Reposting is not the proper way.

Comment: Oh I didn’t know that sorry! I deleted the previous post to make things easier :) again sorry about it. Any help for the question is appreciated.

Comment: While I understand your concern about this, our advice on safety topics is usually limited to "Don't do that!"

Comment: You give far too little information for an answer. How high is the plug above the ground? In what direction will it travel initially? What is its density and shape? What is the gas in the vessel? What is its temperature and density? What air temperature and air density is outside? All that has a major influence on the answer.

Comment: @Mark_space: Have you read up how bullets fly out of guns?